# set one time property value of usercontrol with multiple instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have `user control` with multiple instances in page.
In `page.aspx` function `page_load` I know if I want to visible or hide something in this control for all instance of this control.
In my pages I have `usercontrols` that contain this `usercontrol`.

for each page there are another conditions to visible or hide something in this control - (property cant be static...)

I am looking for a right solution..
thanks!

```
ToPostFloorType floor = new ToPostFloorType();
UserControl uc;
DataTable floors;

floors = floor.FetchFloorTypesByPageID(pageID, iActiveVersion, iWithHeadAndFooter);

for (int i = 0; i < floors.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        PlaceHolder phFloors = this.Page.FindControl("PlaceHolderFloors") as PlaceHolder;
        uc = this.LoadControl("~" + floors.Rows[i]["FloorAscxPrefix"].ToString()) as UserControl;
        uc.ID = floors.Rows[i]["PageTypeFloorTypeID"].ToString();
        uc.EnableViewState = false;
        phFloors.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this recursive extension method to find all references of this control:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(this Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return c;

        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.GetControlsRecursively())
            {
                yield return control;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now its easy with `Enumerable.OfType`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // presuming the type of your control is MyUserControl
        var allUCs = this.GetControlsRecursively().OfType<MyUserControl>();
        foreach (MyUserControl uc in allUCs)
        {
            // do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my user control build on runtime.

Comment: my user control build on runtime. I want to define/ set default value one time and in user control used with this value

Comment: @yael: then show some code, how you are building it? Why can't you set the properties when you create the control?

Comment: I add my code to question. this code run in some user controls that contain specific my user control...

Comment: @yael: you are loading those userconttrols dynamically. So why can't you set the properties you want to set there in the same way you f.e. set the `EnableViewState` property?

Comment: I know it in page.load my user control done in usercontrols that in page.I am looking for a right solution to do it. I dont want to do conditions(if) in all page_load function of instances of my user control. i want to do it once. is it possible?